# Location of Ribbon XML for List View

Tags: list, ribbon, elements-xml

I'm looking for the location of SharePoint ribbon XML for List Views.  I'm just curious to see how Microsoft has coded it.  However, I don't know the location of the xml file.  Could someone put me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the ribbon definitions are stored in this file:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML

Action JS code for most of these ribbon elements you can find here:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.Ribbon.debug.js

Actions for rich text editor ribbon are stored here:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.UI.Rte.debug.js

Comment: Can not find there SPD created Custom Action Buttons. Is there separate folder/files for those?

Comment: The ribbon buttons that SPD creates are likely stored somewhere in database. You can fetch them via API. Get your SPList object first, and then explore UserCustomActions property. This can be done e.g. via PowerShell. For more details, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the following XML into Feature's Elements.xml and try to play with params. The location is `CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
  Id="ShowHelloWorldButton"
  RegistrationType="List"
  RegistrationId="100"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
  Rights="EditListItems">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
         Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
          <Button
           Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls.ShowHelloWorldButton"
           Alt="Show HelloWorld Alert"
           Sequence="1"
           Image32by32="/_layouts/DemoSharePointRibbon/HelloWorld.jpg"
           Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
           LabelText="Hello World"
           TemplateAlias="o1"
           CommandType="General"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
         Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
         CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello World');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Location of Ribbon XML file is :

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML